# Favorites android studio without database

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a list with radios in streaming and I have to add a button of favorites (The typical heart) and when I press it, that radio is saved in another activity (Favorites) and when it leaves and enters the application that is keep the changes but I'm lost and I can not find a solution.

Below can download the project

[My project if you want to download it and try to fix it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17K5jaTUvuChKj329Idch79u1nJFlfyre/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: save the favorites to local storage using storage api https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage and read the data back to get the fav list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) to save favorite if you don't want to use database

Comment: can u help me? can u download my project and implement the sharedPreferences?

Comment: Hi, it is not difficult to do it yourself if you take a look at the link that I provide, In this way you will learn more and the next time you will not have the same problem